# Rails test fails requests did not finish in 60 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

After upgrading rails from 4.2 to 5.2 my test gets stuck on a request while it is working in development server I'm getting following failure on running test suit.

```
Failures:

  1) cold end overview shows cold end stats
     Failure/Error: example.run

     RuntimeError:
       Requests did not finish in 60 seconds
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:94:in `rescue in wait_for_pending_requests'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:91:in `wait_for_pending_requests'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:130:in `reset!'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `block in reset_sessions!'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `reverse_each'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara.rb:314:in `reset_sessions!'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.2/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.2/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:98:in `cleaning'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.2/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.2/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Timeout::Error:
     #   execution expired
     #   /home/asnad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:92:in `sleep'

Top 1 slowest examples (62.59 seconds, 97.0% of total time):
  cold end overview shows cold end stats
    62.59 seconds ./spec/features/cold_end_overview_spec.rb:13

Finished in 1 minute 4.51 seconds (files took 4.15 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

my spec_helper.rb has configurations

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].clean_with(:truncation)

    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      if example.metadata.key?(:js) || example.metadata[:type] == :feature
        # VCR.configure { |c| c.ignore_localhost = true }
        WebMock.allow_net_connect!
        VCR.turn_off!
        VCR.eject_cassette
        example.run
      else
        # WebMock.disable_net_connect!
        VCR.turn_on!
        cassette_name = example.metadata[:full_description]
                               .split(/\s+/, 2)
                               .join('/')
                               .underscore.gsub(/[^\w\/]+/, '_')
        # VCR.configure { |c| c.ignore_localhost = false }
        VCR.use_cassette(cassette_name) { example.run }
        VCR.turn_off!
        WebMock.allow_net_connect!
      end
    end
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  if config.files_to_run.one?
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
end

# Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug
# Selenium::WebDriver.logger.output = 'selenium.log'
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless no-sandbox disable-dev-shm-usage disable-gpu window-size=1200,1500] }, loggingPrefs: { browser: 'ALL' })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end

Chromedriver.set_version '2.39'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = :keep_last_run
```

in my spec the line `sign_in current_user` takes too much time actually it redirects to a page and do not get response even long time while it is working on development environment.
what can be the reason if you need anything else please comment.

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of Capybara - Upgrade to 3.11.1 and see if you still have an issue.  If you do post the error message from that, and the code for the test that is taking over a minute to shutdown.  Also Rails 5.2 doesn't need database_cleaner so you should be able to remove that from your project.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWalpole for your reply I have updated the question with some code from spec_helper.rb for more detail there is another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296233/pgconnectionbad-connection-is-closed-after-upgrading-rails-from-4-2-to-5-2 I have provided much more detail

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I got another clue I changed the javascript_driver to selenium_chrome and it get stuck on a request while it is working on development server.

Comment: Have you updated Capybara and chromedriver (2.44 is the latest and supports current versions of Chrome)?

Comment: Yes I updated the versions @ThomasWalpole

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I got the actual problem have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502225/different-configurations-for-features-test-and-rspec

Comment: And again in that question you're using obsolete versions of Capybara and selenium-webdriver.  If you aren't willing/able to upgrade to current version there is nothing more for me to do here.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I have changed the versions to latest and updated the question please have a look Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just arrived here myself after upgrading from 4.2 to 5.1 and now 5.2, and I'm seeing the same thing in my testing, when I have frozen a test in mid-request with `binding.pry`, I get the message `Requests did not finish in 60 seconds`.  What a great story, skip to the end for tl;dr (I may have figured it out.)

Now I have upgraded all of the gems, incrementally so I can preserve the capacity to bisect and observe the source of interesting changes like this one.  I only noticed this new 60 second timeout after changing over from `chromedriver-helper` which reported it had been deprecated to the new `webdrivers` gem that's taking over, but that seems to be not related as I searched webdrivers for any timeout or 60 second value, and only found references to an unrelated Pull Request #60 (fixes Issue #59).

I checked my gem source directory for this message, `Requests did not finish in 60 seconds`, and found it was not in fact an older version of Capybara, but that it has been raised from versions dating back to at least 3.9.0, and in the most current version 3.24.0 in `lib/capybara/server.rb`.

The object used there is a Timer which you can find an interface to it here, in the helper:

https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/320ee96bb8f63ac9055f7522961a1e1cf8078a8a/lib/capybara/helpers.rb#L79

This particular message is raised out of the method `wait_for_pending_requests` which passes a hard 60 into the `:expire_in` named parameter, then after sends any errors that were encountered in the server thread.  This means the time is not configurable, probably 60 seconds is a reasonable length of time to wait for a web request in progress to complete, although it's a bit inconvenient for my test.

That method is only called in one place, `reset!`, which you can find defined here in `capybara/session.rb`: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/320ee96bb8f63ac9055f7522961a1e1cf8078a8a/lib/capybara/session.rb#L126

The reset! method is an interesting one that comes with some documentation about how it's used.  `@server&.wait_for_pending_requests` looks like it might call wait_for_pending_requests if it has an active server thread in a request, and then raise_server_error! which similarly acts only if `@server&.error` is truthy.

Now we find that reset! comes with two aliases, this message `reset!` is received whenever Capybara calls `cleanup!` or `reset_session!`.  At this point we can probably understand what happened, but it's still a little bit mysterious when I've been using chromedriver-helper and selenium testing for several years, but never recall seeing this 60 second timeout before.  I'm hesitant to point the finger at webdriver, but I don't have any other answers for why this timeout is new.  I haven't done really anything that could account for it but upgrade to this gem, and any other gems, plus clearing out deprecation warnings.

It seems possible that in Rails 5.1+, capybara calls reset! a lot more, maybe more than in between test examples.  Especially when you read that documentation of the method and think about what Single-Page focus there has been now, and consider all of the things that `reset!` documentation tells you it doesn't reset, *clear browser cache/HTML 5 local storage/IndexedDB/Web SQL database/etc* — or maybe I'm imagining it, and this isn't new.  But I'm imagining there are a lot of ways that it can call reset! and not land in this timeout code, that are likely to be driver-dependent.

Did you change to `webdrivers` gem by any chance when you did your Rails upgrade?

**Edit:** I reverted to chromedriver-helper just to be sure, and that wasn't it.  What's actually happening is my test is failing in one thread, but the server has left a `binding.pry` session open.  Capybara has moved onto the next test, and thus to get a fresh session it has called `reset!`, but 60 seconds later I am still in my pry session, and the server is still not ready to serve a root request.  I have a feeling that the threading behavior of capybara has changed, in my memory a pry session opened during a server request would block the test from failing until it had returned.  But that's apparently not what's happening anymore.

How did you arrive here?  I have no idea unfortunately, but this is a fair description of what's happening when that message is received.