# Different configurations for features test and rspec

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, rspec-rails, hiredis

I'm facing a strange issue after updated rails from 4.2 to 5.2. My features test needs following configuration to run

```
config.redis_config = {
  driver: :hiredis,
  host: ENV['REDIS_HOST'] || 'redis',
  port: ENV['REDIS_PORT'] || 6379
}
```

with above config I get error unknow service for model tests which need following configuration

```
config.redis_config = {
  host: ENV['REDIS_HOST'] || 'redis',
  port: ENV['REDIS_PORT'] || 6379
}
```

or

```
config.redis_config = {
  host: ENV['REDIS_HOST'] || 'localhost',
  port: ENV['REDIS_PORT'] || 6379
}
```

By these configuration I get error of timeout for features test. Isn't strange? Some contents from gemfile.lock

```
hiredis (0.6.3)
redis (3.3.5)
rails (~> 5.2.1)
capybara (3.11.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
```